# why iOS mobile cannot use focus()

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari

I'm trying to use the javascript function `focus()`, but it does not work on safari mobile. How do I fix this problem?

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>demo</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         window.onload=function() {
           document.getElementById('username').focus();
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <input type="text" id="username" >
     <input type="text" >
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

iOS does not allow `.focus()` to be fired automatically for security reason.

Comment: Any official reference for this claim?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with an Angular app, and I solved it with a very simple hack.

For starters, you might want to use jQuery; it makes a lot of things clear-cut for you and is more-or-less fully supported. Then, try doing this:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

    setTimeout( $( '#username' ).focus(), 0 );

});
```

Now, I don't exactly know how it works; maybe some rendering issue. But it works for sure.

If you want VanillaJS:

```
window.onload = function() {

    setTimeout( document
                  .getElementById( 'username' ).focus(), 0 );

}
```

I don't know if the VanillaJS version will work.

Comment: Just curious as  to why this answer was voted down? was it because it didnt work?

Comment: I have no clue myself.

Comment: It doesn't work. Problem is that you can't programatically trigger focus on ios device without user interaction.